# SQL server stored procedure unblocking call

Tags: sql-server, clr

This is regarding fundamentals of CLR stored procedures.

Is it possible to create a non-blocking CLR stored procedure?

We make a call to a CLR stored procedure which takes upto 1 minute to execute and ends up locking up the database, hence the need for a non-blocking ClR

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks,
Bruce

Comment: If you want asynchronous handling, you might look into the service broker and the queuing mechanism (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166053(v=sql.105).aspx).  However, it is not quite as simple as writing a stored procedure.

Comment: The fact that CLR blocks the calling session should in no way "*lock up the database*", unless your CLR or your SQL is designed or written incorrectly.

Comment: Use service broker for all asynchronous needs.